# Writing raster file from masked array

Tags: python, raster-calculator, rasterio, numpy

I am doing some raster subtraction to get a canopy height model and I am struggling to write the output as a raster. The original datasets were .tif files in ESPG 27700 created from LiDAR. I used masked arrays as I know there are some no data values (-3.048...) in the original tif files. Ideally I would like to return the result of the raster calculation as a geotif with the same crs. The code I have used is as follows...

```
grnd_DTM = rasterio.open(ground_raster_full_path) #path variable to original bare earth tif
ground_array = grnd_DTM.read(1, masked = True) # reading bare earth raster as a masked numpy array
sfc_DTM = rasterio.open(surface_model_full_path) #path variable to surface model tif
surface_array= sfc_DTM.read(1, masked = True) #reading surface model raster as masked numpy array 
canopy_ht = surface_array-ground_array # 

profile = ground_raster_full_path.profile
band_number = 1
# to update the dtype
profile.update(dtype=canopy_ht.dtype)

with rasterio.open(raster_folder+'canopy_ht.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(target, band_number)
```

Unfortunately this is giving me the following error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-4914f600fe68> in <module>
      5 canopy_ht = surface_array-ground_array
      6 
----> 7 profile = ground_raster_full_path.profile
      8 band_number = 1
      9 # to update the dtype

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'profile'
```

I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: ground_raster_full_path is just the name of the file, ie a string. It has no profile attribute. Maybe it should be grnd_DTM.profile instead?

Comment: You should put in your code snippet used python modules. The **ground_raster_full_path** is a string (without 'profile' attribute) and  'profile' method doesn't exist in **rasterio** (it is 'profiles' instead).

Comment: @xunilk `profile` is a property of a rasterio dataset, not `profiles`